# Unable to 'bundle install' RoR 3.0.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler, iterm

Here is a link to my screen cap. https://i.stack.imgur.com/FL0nW.jpg (SO doesn't allow noobs to post pics)

The problem.

Trying to bundle install and it keeps throwing the 'this version requires a different version of bundler' error. So I uninstall the current version, check my versions of bundler and it still appears. I go to uninstall it again and it tell me it doesn't exist. Can someone please lend a thought.

EDIT: Contents of Gemfile

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3-ruby', '1.0.0', :require => 'sqlite3'

# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug'

# Bundle the extra gems:
# gem 'bj'
# gem 'nokogiri'
# gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
# gem 'aws-s3', :require => 'aws/s3'

# Bundle gems for the local environment. Make sure to
# put test-only gems in this group so their generators
# and rake tasks are available in development mode:
# group :development, :test do
#   gem 'webrat'
# end
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of your gemfile? Also just try running `gem install bundler` to ensure you have the latest version.

Comment: Added contents. I ran gem install bundler. It gives me 1.1.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to manually install **bundler 1.0.0** using `gem install bundler --version "1.0.0"` and then run again `bundle install`.

**UPDATE**: Looking at the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CIRB.jpg) in the other answer it seems you already have bundler 1.0.0, BTW give it a try anyway. It seems the bundle command still points to the newer version, what do you get if you run `bundle -v`?

Comment: http://imgur.com/BIt0M 

Here's the latest image. I have all versions uninstalled except 1.0.0 and it still tells me my current version is 1.1.3 even though when I go to uninstall version 1.1.3 it says it doesn't exist.

Comment: Have you closed the terminal and then tried again? I guess the environment is not up-to-date and it still points to the newer, uninstalled, bundler version.

Comment: I did try that. I just went through and installed everything again. Seemed to be the long way around but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The error is at it says in the screenshot, you are using rails 3.0.1.

do uninstall without version

```
gem uninstall bundler
```

it will ask you which version you want to remove then remove it, select 1.3.1 to uninstall, do a bundle install again and if it still shows error post it back here.

Comment: http://imgur.com/aiTaB

It's acting very strange. It uninstalled but still throws the error.

Comment: paste the output of `bundle exec gem list` and `gem list` also uninstall the other version of bundle you dont need